# May OnCalendar systemd timer start earlier?

Tags: timer, systemd

I have a service that is started by "OnCalendar" systemd timer.

As I understood,  it may start not exactly at the time specified in "OnCalendar" parameter
but a bit later, due to accuracy.

The question is if accuracy works in another direction too, i.e. may a service start
a bit earlier?

Is this info explicitly stated somewhere in systemd docs?

For my service it is important not to start earlier, than specified in "OnCalendar" parameter.
A bit later is ok.

Answer (score 0):

The AccuracySec parameter may help you here.  By default, tasks started with OnCalendar start within AccuracySec seconds (the default is one minute)

More about this setting is in the systemd.timer documentation:

> Specify the accuracy the timer shall elapse with. Defaults to 1min. The timer is scheduled to elapse within a time window starting with the time specified in OnCalendar=, OnActiveSec=, OnBootSec=, OnStartupSec=, OnUnitActiveSec= or OnUnitInactiveSec= and ending the time configured with AccuracySec= later. Within this time window, the expiry time will be placed at a host-specific, randomized, but stable position that is synchronized between all local timer units. This is done in order to optimize power consumption to suppress unnecessary CPU wake-ups. To get best accuracy, set this option to 1us. Note that the timer is still subject to the timer slack configured via systemd-system.conf(5)'s TimerSlackNSec= setting. See prctl(2) for details. To optimize power consumption, make sure to set this value as high as possible and as low as necessary.

Source: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html